# Automated text analysis software?

Tags: text-analysis

Any automated easy software for text analysis? 
I need to perform text analysis on following text:
http://www.columbia.edu/itc/mealac/pritchett/00generallinks/macaulay/txt_minute_education_1835.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you ever found a solution, but there is a new online tool at http://text-ananlyzer.com that will provide Natural Language Processing, Sentiment Analysis and allow you to find the nuggets in the results via its sentence shopping views. It can hit that URL and analyze the text for you.  It has all kinds of tools to dynamically drill into the results. Hope this helps.